# php fwrite() reports characters written, but they're not there

Tags: php, fwrite

I provide this directory & file:

```
$path = $_POST['q2Path'];
$file = "test.txt";
// q2Path == "C:\Users\micah\Desktop\only_dir_named_this"
```

The code runs this block:

```
$write_str = "TEST TEST TEST";
$fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("can't open: $path\\$file");
$chars = fwrite($fh, $write_str) or die("can't write to: $path\\$file");
fclose($fh) or die("can't close: $path\\$file");
echo "<pre>&gt; Appended $chars characters to: $path\\$file</pre>";
```

This is the browser output:

> Appended 14 characters to: C:\Users\micah\Desktop\only_dir_named_this\test.txt

And in the end, the file is empty and the 'last modified' timestamp hasn't changed.  I'm not sure what's up.  I'm using ZendServer on Win7.  Perhaps there's a php.ini setting that needs adjustment?  I've never had a problem with a simple file write...

Comment: What happens if you attempt to write to a file that doesn't exist?  
Is there a test.txt in the directory with the PHP script?  Because you don't have a path specified, it probably is writing to that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write `$path\\$file`, but you do `fopen($file, 'a')`

It should be

```
$fh = fopen($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, 'a') or die("can't open: $path\\$file");
```

Comment: That would mean that it *is* writing to `test.txt`, but the file is in the same directory as the PHP script.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  And sure enough, there are a ton of test files in the directory with a string for each frustrated page-refresh I did in the last 30 min.